# .NET MAUI Blazor On page navigation

Tags: navigation, blazor, maui

There seems to be very little on the subject.

How can you click a button or an < a > tag and navigate to a different part of the page?

The only way I thought was possible was using simple html anchor tags that point to an element Id, sadly this does not work.

I would like vanilla MAUI Blazor options but if a third party component works, that's fine too.

Comment: What does the page in ` navigate to a different part of the page` mean? A razor page or a contentpage? I created a sample and try to add a label in the mainpage, but the razor page will not show. The app seems freezed.

Comment: It sounds like you’re experiencing a different issue. In answer to your question. It’s a Maui blazor app, so razor. Navigate in this context means moving from one part of the page to another part of the page. I.e Instead of scrolling, pressing a button at the top of the page that scrolls to a section at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new sample to test and used the js function to scroll to the element id replace the scrolling.

In the index.html:

```
<script>
     window.scrollToElementId = (elementId) => {
          console.info('scrolling to element', elementId);
          var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
          if (!element) {
                 console.warn('element was not found', elementId);
             }
          element.scrollIntoView();
       }
</script>
```

In the razor:

```
@inject IJSRuntime js

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ScrollTo">Goto The Element</button>

  .... a lot of elements

<p id="ap">The bottom of the page.</p>

@code {
      private void ScrollTo()
      {
            ScrollToElementId("ap");
      }
      private async void ScrollToElementId(string elementId)
      {
            await js.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToElementId", elementId);
      }
}
```